# Export html report to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have an html report having different sections like report header, report footer and the report data which needs to be exported to excel as it is. I am able to do this but the format of the report in excel is not proper. How can i make the format of the report as it is in the html report

i have used the following code to export html report with header and data to excel

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
string filename = "ECC_EMEA_" + String.Format("{0:dd_MMM_yy}", DateTime.Now.Date) + "_Summary.xls";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
string htmlString = sb.ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count;i++ )
    Response.Write("\t"); ;
Response.Write(htmlString);
Response.End();
```

Comment: how are you currently doing it?

Comment: Please provide what you did that generates inconsistency in your format. Have you tried using ClipBoard - basically copy and paste it onto Excel?

Comment: code you provided doesn't explain the behavior. what you can do is, when page is rendered in browser (and looks ok) click mouse right button, from menu choose `view page source` (or something similar, as it depends on browser). now that you have html source of the page, search the source for unsupported html elements, css styles... list of unsupported elements, styles you can get from the link that I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

ms office html rendering engine is really limited... if you want excel to display report in a proper format you have to build it only with supported html elements, css...

from my experience and from what i remember something like this is not supported (had a similar task to yours)

```
<table STYLE="background-image:url('url')">
```

you have to google to see what other limitations are and what elements, css properties are supported.

**EDITED**

here I have found a [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx). **Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007**. Excel html, css limitations will be quite similar to this.